# What is the difference between `matplotlib.rc` and `matplotlib.rcParams`? And which one to use?

Tags: matplotlib

I have been using `matplotlib.rc` in my scripts to preprocess my plots. But recently I have realized that using `matplotlib.rcParams` is much easier before doing a quick plot interactively (e.g. via IPython). This got me into thinking what difference between the two is.

I searched the matplotlib documentation wherein no clear answer was provided in this regard. Moreover, when I issue `type(matplotlib.rc)`, the interpreter says that it is a function. On the other hand, when I issue `type(matplotlib.rcParams)`, I am told that it is a class object. These two answers are not at all helpful and hence I would appreciate some help differentiating the two.

Additionally, I would like to know which one to prefer over the other.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I went through this question: [What's the difference between matplotlib.rc and matplotlib.pyplot.rc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658412/whats-the-difference-between-matplotlib-rc-and-matplotlib-pyplot-rc) but the answers are specific to the difference between the `matplotlib` instance and the `pyplot` instance of the two types I am enquiring about and, hence, is also not that helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matplotlib.rc` is a function that updates `matplotlib.rcParams`.

`matplotlib.rcParams` is a dict-subclass that provides a validate key-value map for Matplotlib configuration.

The docs for `mpl.rc` are at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html?highlight=rc#matplotlib.rc and the [code is here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/6c940e87035ea4b27a207e5bc46194025999435a/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py#L868-L941).

The class definition of `RcParams` is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/6c940e87035ea4b27a207e5bc46194025999435a/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py#L561-L672) and it the instance is created [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/6c940e87035ea4b27a207e5bc46194025999435a/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py#L851-L863).

If we look at the guts of `matplotlib.rc` we see:

```py
    for g in group:
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            name = aliases.get(k) or k
            key = '%s.%s' % (g, name)
            try:
                rcParams[key] = v
            except KeyError as err:
                raise KeyError(('Unrecognized key "%s" for group "%s" and '
                                'name "%s"') % (key, g, name)) from err
```

where we see that `matplotlib.rc` does indeed update `matplotlib.rcParams` (after doing some string formatting).

You should use which ever one is more convenient for you.  If you know exactly what key you want to update, then interacting with the dict-like is better, if you want to set a whole bunch of values in a group then `mpl.rc` is likely better!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the snippet showing exactly where the handshake is happening between `rc()` and `rcParams` -- this is what I wanted to know. Moreover, I too realized the same thing as you mentioned in your last statement. Thanks again.